# Yii2 - Imagine - creating a thumbnail and keeping transparent background

Tags: yii2, php-imagine

I am trying to upload an image and scale it to maximum 200px width or 200px height depends which is bigger, using Imagine.

I read this link: [Imagine](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-imagine-baseimage.html#thumbnail%28%29-detail) where it says:

> If one of thumbnail dimensions is set to null, another one is calculated automatically based on aspect ratio of original image.

I Tried this code to change the width:

```
Image::thumbnail($target, 200, null)->save($target_to);
```

got an error:
Exception Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException with message Length side cannot be 0 or negative.

I am also trying to upload png files with transparent background.
Looking at the same link it says:

> If thumbnail mode is ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET, the original image is scaled down so it is fully contained within the thumbnail dimensions. The rest is filled with background that could be configured via yii\imagine\Image::$thumbnailBackgroundColor and yii\imagine\Image::$thumbnailBackgroundAlpha.

Looking at the links they give, it says it will fill:

> $thumbnailBackgroundAlpha public static property (available since version 2.0.4)
>   Background alpha (transparency) to use when creating thumbnails in ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET mode with both width and height specified. Default is solid.
>   public static string $thumbnailBackgroundAlpha = 100
>   $thumbnailBackgroundColor public static property (available since version 2.0.4) Background color to use when creating thumbnails in ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_INSET mode with both width and height specified. Default is white.
>   public static string $thumbnailBackgroundColor = 'FFF'

I have 2 questions:

1. Will this keep the transparent background?
   public static string $thumbnailBackgroundAlpha = 100
   $thumbnailBackgroundColor public static property (available since version 2.0.4)
2. I don't want to give width and height, only one dimension so the image will be resized accordingly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image thumbnail] As in latest releases, passing null as an argument is making the respective `null` argument value as zero and hence exception is thrown. You can solve it using as shown in the image. As you can see in the code, I have passed only width parameter i.e 400 and calculated height using the same and passed to the thumbnail method.